# Get text from system tray app menu

Tags: vpn, system-tray

I would like to access text displayed in the systray menu of this application: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/

It is a VPN client that can do port forwarding and it displays the port number in its systray menu.

So I am looking for an easy way to access this port number (but generally any systray text) with script.

Thanks